# How to obtain data from a listview and pass it to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listactivity

My app returns albums from the media store and places them in a listview. When an album is clicked on, it opens another listview which contains the songs pertaining to that album. But when I click on any song, the app crashes. I want to be able to obtain the filepath of the selected song and pass it to another activity that plays that song. Here's my code:
    public class Albums extends ListActivity {
    Cursor cursor;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    String[] columns = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM };

    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns, null, null, null);

    String[] displayFields = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM };
    int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields,
            displayViews));

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, };

        String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + "=?";

        String whereVal[] = { cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)) };

        String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;

        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns, where, whereVal, orderBy);

        String[] displayFields = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME };
        int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields,
                displayViews));

    }
}


}
```

This is what is contained in the Logcat:

```
07-18 17:44:20.327: D/libEGL(30458): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-18 17:44:20.387: D/libEGL(30458): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
07-18 17:44:20.407: D/libEGL(30458): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
07-18 17:44:20.437: D/libEGL(30458): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
07-18 17:44:20.607: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(30458): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
07-18 17:44:20.667: D/memalloc(30458): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51fcf000 size:1536000 fd:62
07-18 17:44:20.697: D/OpenGLRenderer(30458): Enabling debug mode 0
07-18 17:44:20.818: D/memalloc(30458): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52156000 size:1536000 fd:65
07-18 17:44:40.737: D/OpenGLRenderer(30458): has fontRender patch
07-18 17:44:41.047: D/memalloc(30458): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x526bd000 size:1536000 fd:68
07-18 17:44:43.750: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(30458): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
07-18 17:44:43.770: D/memalloc(30458): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52834000 size:1536000 fd:71
07-18 17:44:43.960: D/memalloc(30458): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52bab000 size:1536000 fd:78
07-18 17:44:43.980: D/OpenGLRenderer(30458): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-18 17:44:44.981: D/memalloc(30458): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51ecf000 size:1536000 fd:63
07-18 17:44:47.454: E/CursorWindow(30458): Failed to read row 4, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 11 rows, 5 columns.
07-18 17:44:47.454: D/AndroidRuntime(30458): Shutting down VM
07-18 17:44:47.454: W/dalvikvm(30458): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac7228)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 4, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:491)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:118)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at com.project.helixplayer.Albums.onListItemClick(Albums.java:49)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:326)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1077)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2533)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3198)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 17:44:47.494: E/AndroidRuntime(30458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): killProcess, pid=30458
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-18 17:44:49.846: D/Process(30458): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 17:44:49.846: I/Process(30458): Sending signal. PID: 30458 SIG: 9
```

Comment: as i thought: "Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it." . In order to access to your Cursor, try to use my code. You don't have to do a query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your question and add LogCat. I don't know what are you doing on your itemClick (correct me if i didn't understand): you use cursor.moveToPosition(position) without determining where you take the cursor; then you take columns and other query staff; finally you create a list.

Long story short, it seems that you are creating a list when you click on an item!
Change your code on  method in this way:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listViev.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // Find your data on cursor and launch your second activity in order to show album's tracks
}
```

**EDIT**

After our discussion on comments below, i think you have to change your structure on your project.

Add a fist activity wich contain a list of your album; when you click on one item, launch second activity wich will contain a list of album's tracks.

If you use database, it will be more easy to query and show data.

Comment: I've added the Logcat. Tell me if it expounds my query.

Comment: When the activity starts, a list of albums is displayed. When I click on an album, songs in that album are shown in a listview(This is handled by the onListItemClick() method). If I click on a song in the list of songs, I want to extract its path and send it to another activity but that's where the app crashes.

Comment: @diamondtrust66 does all operations are done in the same activity?

Comment: @diamondtrust66 forgive me if i'm a little rude, but IMHO this is not the correct way to achieve what you want: see my edited answer.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thanks a lot.